# Jquery .load disables all functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

Merry Christmas everybody!!!
I have a personal message system in my page. To show and manipulate the messages I use jquery. This is the file I want to talk about:

```
<!-- get the message and show it -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.message').click(function() {
    var msgId = $(this).attr('id').replace('msg','');
    $.get('retrieve_msg_content.php?msgID='+msgId,function(data) {
        $('#target').html(data);
    })
// change status to read (1). type: 'POST',
$.ajax({ type: 'POST', url: 'change_status.php', data: "msgID="+msgId+"&action=read", });
});

// if img X is clicked, change status to erased(3)!
$('.delete_msg').click(function() {
    var msgId = $(this).attr('id').replace('msg','');
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST', url: 'change_status.php', data: "msgID="+msgId+"&action=delete",
  success: function(){
$('#message_line'+msgId).hide('slow');
$('#target').html('Haz click en un mensaje para leerlo!');

$('#refresh').load("retrieve_msg_received.php");
}
});
});
</script>
<!-- END of get the message and show it -->

<div id="refresh">
<?php include 'retrieve_msg_received.php'; ?>
</div>

<span id="target"></span>
```

Let me explain now. First section: when you click on a message, it calls retrieve_msg_content.php, replaces the content of the message in the #target and then it changes the status to '1' (read).
The second section is to erase a message: it changes the status of the message to '3', then it hides the message just erased, puts something nice in the #target and reloads the message list. Everything works fine until you try to read another message after the messages had been reloaded. For some reason you click in any message but it's not shown and I don't see any activity (no calls to other files -retrieve_msg_content.php).
By inspecting the elements I can see they are alike before and after the 'refresh'[image: before refresh] [image: after refresh]

before the refresh (on top), you can see #target (A ver...)
after the refresh on bottom (same class, same id):

I hope you guys can help. Thanks!!!

Comment: Check your `retrieve_msg_content.php` . May be it has some invalid syntax.

Comment: well, it works fine before the 'refreshing'. I don't think that's the problem. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `.load()`, you're replacing your existing elements with new elements that don't have any event handlers.

You need to add your event handlers [using `.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) with a child selector to handle events for all future elements that match the selectors.

Comment: would you mind explaining your answer a little bit more? should I put .on(.load("retrieve_messages_rec.php")) it doesn't look right to me :-/

Comment: @cbarg: you should attach your events using `.on()`, like this: `$('.delete_msg').on('click', function() {...`.

Comment: @Clive: No; that won't help.  You need `$(some container).on('click', '.delete_msg', function() { ... })`   http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @SLaks: Are you sure? The first example on the docs page seems to indicate that would work fine

Comment: @Clive: Yes, but it wouldn't be live.  That's equivalent to what he has already.  Live events need a separate selector.

Comment: Actually I set $("#display_messages tbody tr").on('click', '.delete_msg', function() {...} following an example in api.query.com, but I am getting 'Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'' all the time.

Comment: @cbarg: Upgrade to jQuery 1.7 or use `.delegate` instead.  Also, the outer selector must match an element that does not get replaced by the AJAX call.

Comment: Thanks very much, guys!!! I also had to set the .on() also in the first section of my code: $("#refresh").on("click", ".message", function(){...}